# Google image search for my website with get result and fetch from my database

Tags: php, search, google-api

here i have a data base on all type of birds. if someone upload a bird picture i want to send the images to **Google search** to get the bird name. if i get the bird name i'll fetch details from my database and show. but i cant find any ***Google image search code***.

Please help me to complete my project.

Thanks  in advance. sorry for poor English.

Comment: Mind adding what have you done so far?

Comment: i just want to show the fetch result on a page that it. it's my a little project. plz help

Comment: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide this is where you get the code..

Comment: Let you know what I actually want.

Create a normal HTML page with a form. make a field field type file upload. when I pick a picture form send that picture to google. Google give me response with his name.

Example: go to google and upload a picture and then google give you a name. That name I want my page.

Comment: Please Help me how can I get this ??

Comment: Please pick a flower image. see the result, Like: Best guess for this image: "Flower name"